# WebBrowser control with an automated proxy login

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, proxy, webbrowser-control

I have a windows form application that contains a `WebBrowser` control. The idea is for the `WebBrowser` to surf websites without user interaction. The `WebBrowser` goes through a proxy to access the internet.

I can see the requests coming through on the proxy, but they are being denied because it fails proxy authentication.

I have added the `Proxy-Authorization: Basic` header. This works for a normal http page but it does not seem to work https:

```
var credentialStringValue = "proxyUser:proxyPassword";
byte[] credentialByteArray = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentialStringValue);
var credentialBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(credentialByteArray);

string Headers = string.Format("Proxy-Authorization: Basic {0}{1}", credentialBase64String, Environment.NewLine);

ws.Navigate(url,TargetFrameName,PostData,Headers);
```

Where `ws` is equal to `new WebBrowser()`. The credentials are correct, because it works when I do it manually.

Any idea as to how I can programatically Authenticate the proxy credentials?

Comment: @Abat - Sure - no one is. Next time you do a dual edit just add the reason in the edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
 // do what you want with proxy class
WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(host, port)
{
    Credentials = ...
}

HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
webRequest.Proxy = webProxy;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.DocumentStream = receiveStream;
```

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking for. He wants to run the entire WebBrowser through the Proxy. Are you suggesting he rewrites everything to work the way you suggest? He may as well make the control.

Comment: @Kyle: My proposal is about not to use `Navigate()` but get HTML via WebRequest with WebProxy, and render it using WebBrowser control

Comment: I see that. What happens when someone clicks a link on the site?

Comment: @Kyle: You're right. As workaround - override all links click and performs a request in the same manner, via proxy.

Comment: @Kyle: All methods to solve OP's problem I googled is about to use P/Invoke

Answer (score 2):

None of those are going to work. Because of windows security features, it will always pop up the username and password dialog. You first have to store the credentials in windows credentials. the first thing you need to do is download the [CredentialManagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/) package via NuGet Package manager. You first have to store the proxy information in the registry, with username and password. Here is the code for the registry

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
        public const int INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39;
        public const int INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37;

 static void setProxyRegistry(string proxyhost, bool proxyEnabled, string username, string password)
        {
            const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
            const string subkey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
            const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;

            Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ProxyServer", proxyhost, RegistryValueKind.String);
            Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ProxyEnable", proxyEnabled ? "1" : "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ProxyPass", password, RegistryValueKind.String);
            Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ProxyUser", username, RegistryValueKind.String);

            //<-loopback>;<local>
            Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ProxyOverride", "*.local", RegistryValueKind.String);


            // These lines implement the Interface in the beginning of program 
            // They cause the OS to refresh the settings, causing IP to realy update
            InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        }
```

then you need to set the credentials

```
 Credential credentials= new Credential
            {
                Username = "Usernmae",
                Password = "Password",
                Target = "Target (usualy proxy domain)",
                Type = CredentialType.Generic,
                PersistanceType = PersistanceType.Enterprise
            };
            credentials.Save();
```

I use this with .NET 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution posted here:

http://www.journeyintocode.com/2013/08/c-webbrowser-control-proxy.html

It uses `winnet.dll` as well as a couple of interfaces on the `WebBrowser` class, including `IAuthenticate`.

I havent been able to try it but looks promising.